# C struct for dynamic 2d array: error for object 0x7ffeee94ab80: pointer being freed was not allocated

Tags: c, memory

I'm using clang-1000.11.45.5 on a macbook. I'm trying to make a structure for a dynamically allocated 2D matrix. It looks like this:

```
typedef struct
{
    int m_rows;
    int m_cols;
    double **arr;
    double *data;
} t_mtrx;

t_mtrx *init_mtrx(int rows, int cols)
{
    t_mtrx *A = malloc(sizeof(t_mtrx));
    A -> m_rows = rows;
    A -> m_cols = cols;
    A -> arr = malloc(rows * sizeof(*A->arr));
    A -> data = malloc(rows * cols * sizeof(*A->data));

    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++, A -> data += cols)
        A -> arr[i] = A -> data;

    return A;
}

void del_mtrx(t_mtrx *A)
{
    free(A->data);
    free(A->arr);
}
```

Basically in each matrix there's two pointers:

`*data`: All of the elements in the matrix laid out in a 1D array

`**arr`: Pointers to the address of the first element of every column

Everything has been working fine with this except for making a deconstructor.

```
int main()
{
    int rows = 3;
    int cols = 3;

    double ra[] = {1, 3223, 5},
           rb[] = {2, 0, -99},
           rc[] = {14, 134, 130};

    t_mtrx A = *init_mtrx(rows, cols);

    A.arr[0] = ra;
    A.arr[1] = rb;
    A.arr[2] = rc;

    print_mtrx(&A);

    del_mtrx(&A);

}
```

When I run this, everything works except for `del_mtrx`.

```
$ ./a.out 

[[   1.00, 3223.00,    5.00],
 [   2.00,    0.00,  -99.00],
 [  14.00,  134.00,  130.00]] 3 x 3
a.out(684,0x10533e5c0) malloc: *** error for object 0x7fea65c02a48: pointer being freed was not allocated
a.out(684,0x10533e5c0) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Abort trap: 6
```

I know the problem is with `free(A -> data);` because when I comment it out there isn't an error, but I'm not sure how else to free it.

Comment: `A -> data += cols` - don't do that. You lose the original value of the address stored there, at least from that pointer. Thus, `free(A->data)` is a recipe for undefined behavior. Use a local temp to walk that row pointer up the buffer. And fyi, you're using that api wrong anyway. You're leaking memory dreadfully

Comment: `t_mtrx *A = malloc(sizeof(t_mtrx));` this is a memory leak, return `t_mtrx` not a pointer to it. Let C copy the structure for you.

Answer (score 2):

There are two flaws in the code

- The `for` loop is changing the value of `A->data`. The modified `A->data` cannot be passed to `free`, since it no longer points to the beginning of the memory block.
- The structure itself is not freed, resulting in a memory leak. A simple rule of memory management is that every `malloc` must be have a corresponding `free`.

Fixing the second problem is easy, just `free(A)` in the `del_mtrx` function. The first problem can be fixed as shown in the code below. Note that he addresses assigned to `A->arr` are the same, but `A->data` is not modified.

```
t_mtrx *init_mtrx(int rows, int cols)
{
    t_mtrx *A = malloc(sizeof(t_mtrx));
    A->m_rows = rows;
    A->m_cols = cols;
    A->arr = malloc(rows * sizeof(*A->arr));
    A->data = malloc(rows * cols * sizeof(*A->data));

    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        A->arr[i] = A->data + (i * cols);

    return A;
}

void del_mtrx(t_mtrx *A)
{
    free(A->data);
    free(A->arr);
    free(A);
}
```

There are also two problems in `main`

- The pointer returned by `init_mtrx` should not be dereferenced, but simply used as is. Dereferencing the pointer makes a needless copy of the structure, and creates a memory leak.
- Assigning the arrays overwrites the pointers, which makes the `A->data` completely irrelevant.

Here's a sample implementation for `main` that copies the data into the allocated memory. Note that if you don't want to copy the data, then the `init_mtrx` function shouldn't be allocating memory for `A->data` in the first place.

```
int main(void)
{
    int rows = 3;
    int cols = 3;

    double ra[] = {1, 3223, 5},
           rb[] = {2, 0, -99},
           rc[] = {14, 134, 130};

    t_mtrx *A = init_mtrx(rows, cols);

    memcpy(A->arr[0], ra, sizeof(ra));
    memcpy(A->arr[1], rb, sizeof(rb));
    memcpy(A->arr[2], rc, sizeof(rc));

    print_mtrx(A);

    del_mtrx(A);
}
```

Comment: `main` has to change too, or the OP's code will be freeing an automatic address. The deref after call on `init_matrx` is the dead giveaway there (and the ensuing `&A` argument to `del_mtrx`).

Comment: @user3386109 Also, fyi, just using `A->arr[i] = A->data + (i * cols);` will remove the need or `offset`, and still prevent modifying `A->data`. Just an alternate way around the same thing. That pretty much covers it. I leave the mess of the OP's hard pointer replacement within their managed structure using automatic addresses from `main()` declared arrays as the ticking time bomb that it is.

Comment: @WhozCraig you are 100% wrong as the memory for the struct is dynamically allocated and it will remain after the function return. The address to this memory is only returned and it is 100% OK. The existence of the holding pointer (or its scope) does not matter as only the value is returned.

Comment: @P__J__ with all respect, you have no idea what you're talking about. What, in the OP's code, in `main()` do you think `&A` refers to, and what do you think will happen when *that* is passed to the `del_mtrx` **in this answer** ?, specifically, the `free(A)` at the tail of that function ? And fyi, "100% wrong" is redundant when it comes to memory management; either it's right, or its wrong; partial credit doesn't apply. With the change just-posted, the `main` in *this* answer is now correct for the implementation of `del_mtrx` *in this answer*.

Comment: @WhozCraig Thanks for the suggestion. The `i * cols` implementation does look cleaner.

Comment: of course he needs to free A. I was writing the about the function not the `main`

Comment: @P__J__ It was my bad for not looking at how the OP was using the structure in `main`. I hope I've cleared that up now.

Answer (score 1):

Your A->data when you return from the function does not point to the beginning of the allocated memory anymore